# Dictionary-like search using SQL Server FULL-TEXT

Tags: sql, sql-server, dictionary, full-text-search, ranking

I am trying to create a dictionary for my website.
Searching for 'server' using FREETEXTTable & Rank DESC returns:

1. name server - A program or server that maps human-readable names..
2. server - One who serves; a waitress or waiter.
3. server - A tray for dishes; a salver.
   4...

'server' is obviously closer to 'server' than 'name server'. How do I fix the ranking?

I can not just reverse to ASC because there are even worse matches.
Top 3 results for 'God' are 'act of God', 'Lamb of God', 'Le God'..

Edit: Sorry for any confusion. nameserver, server, server.. are in a single column called 'word' this is the column that is queried with full-text search. The definitions are in the next column 'definition' and returned as query results.

Comment: My guess is that 1 contains server twice. Maybe you can restrict the fulltext index to column 1.

Comment: Thanks thats a good thought I have used FREETEXTTABLE(Dictionary, word, @0, 20). Is this enough to restrict the index to the 'word' column and not the definition column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use union to solve the problem of your result ordering problem ..

like

```
select * from your_table_name where col_name = 'server'
union 
select * from your_table_name where col_name like '%server%' order by col1,col2..
```

this query should give you first row with full text search and then with partial search ..

clarification .. 
please note that by `col_name` i meant to say about the column name what you have for your words.. 
say your table structure is ..

dictionary-
( c_word ,
  c_definition,
  c_synonyms
)

then you have to modify my query as

```
select * from Dictionary where c_word = 'server'
union 
select * from Dictionary where c_word like '%server%' order by c_definition,c_synonyms
```

so that this query will show first where c_word value exactly match the word 'server' followed by the partial search..

for dynamic query-- you need to replace `'server'` with the variable where you are getting requested keyword for search .

Comment: You'll need to add something else to each individual select in order to dictate order. A union could feasibly be assembled and presented in any order, not necessarily in the same order as the queries you put together. Also, these queries are completely ignoring the `FULLTEXT` part of the question - 'server' isn't all by itself in a column (which your first select implies).

Comment: For the example I gave I agree the LIKE statement might give a closer match but that is not always the case as full-text can give close results when LIKE does not give any. Sometimes the user might search for the definition of a short phrase or ambiguous words. The dataset I am using is from wiktionary.org and there are lots of results.

Comment: @user759885 if you want to add condition for short phrase also then you have to add this condition in this query also ..

Answer (score 0):

I used the PATINDEX function to do this at one point.  Something like the following:

```
SELECT
    Word,
    Definition
FROM
    FREETEXTTABLE(Dictionary, Word, @search, 20) AS Matches
    INNER JOIN Dictionary ON
        Matches.Key = Dictionary.ID
ORDER BY
    CASE PATINDEX('%' + @search + '%', Word) 
        WHEN -1 THEN 1000
        ELSE PATINDEX('%' + @search + '%', Word) 
    END
```

It doesn't perform too terribly since you're using the full text index to get a smaller result set (max 20 as well, in this case).  PATINDEX finds a string within an expression.  If the search string doesn't exist within the expression, it returns -1.  This might occur if you're also searching definitions,  if your search matches on a synonym or stemmed word (eg: you search for "took" so "take" is returned), or if your search involves multiple words.  The CASE statement sorts those results to the end.